# Nginx HTTPS issue to redirect from www to non-www

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx

I need to configure nginx for one of my rails application to route some pages through SSL but facing problem with configuration.

I've a SSL certificate where common name is example.com and my site is routing to example.com from www.example.com

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
  upstream unicorn {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /certificate path;
    ssl_certificate_key  /key path;
  }

  server {
    listen 80 default deferred;
    root /public path;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
    location @unicorn {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://unicorn;
    }
    client_max_body_size 50M;
  }
```

I've tried different configuration as well but nothing work. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for that.

Comment: There's more traffic (and a higher degree of expertise) for nginx on serverfault.com than there is on stackoverflow, i'd recommend asking this there instead.

Comment: When listening on 80 your $scheme = http so you are looping back, if you want 80 -> 443 then don't use scheme, force https. With 443 the same, it looks like you created a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue has been resolved by doing modifications below, answering this as it might help someone else:

- Removed `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` from `default_server` block.
- Removed URL overwriting from SSL server block.
- Added `ssl_protocols` and `ssl_ciphers` to SSL server block

The configuration look like below after modification:

```
upstream unicorn {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /example.com/current/public;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

    ......
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols    TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this help.

I have had a same problem. I struggle with it for a longtime until I redirect from `ApplicationController`

In the ApplicationController:

```
 before_filter :redirect_subdomain

  def redirect_subdomain
    if request.host == 'www.example.com.au'
      redirect_to 'https://example.com.au' + request.fullpath
    end
  end
```

Comment: Or putting the answer from Mr H in nginx config terms  
    server {  
        listen 80;  
        server_name www.example.com;  
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 permanent;  
     }`
(add carriage returns where required, i am not able to <pre> this snippet)